How to count duplicate values in an array
{% set valuesCars = ['bmw', 'mercedes', 'seat', 'porsche', 'seat', 'bmw', 'seat'] %}

{% set valuesIntegers = [27, 32, 36, 36, 27, 32, 32] %}

{% set counts = {} %}

{# Change valuesCars to valuesIntegers to output the integers #}
{% for value in valuesCars %}
    {% if counts[value] is not defined %}
        {% set counts = counts|merge({ (value): 1 }) %}
    {% else %}
        {% set counts = counts|merge({ (value): counts[value] + 1 }) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for key, count in counts %}
    {{ key }}: {{ count }}
{% endfor %}

For valuesCars I get the correct output:
bmw: 2 
mercedes: 1 
seat: 3 
porsche: 1
For valuesIntegers I don't get the desired output. I get this:
0: 1 
1: 1 
2: 1 
3: 1 
4: 1 
5: 1 
6: 1
The desired output should be
27 : 2
32: 3
36 : 2
What am I'm missing here?

Please read the part about merging numeric indices and the issue attached. A "workaround" is also included in the answer, have a look at the part where I make the numeric index into a string with 'id_'~raw._id.id

@DarkBee : Thanks for your responses. I looked into your question on stackoverflow and your issue on github, this helped me to find a solution. Kind of hacky in my opinion. But strange behavior for the numeric index ‍♂️

Closing this question, does this mean other users of stackoverflow won't see the question and answer anymore?

No - When a question is closed as a duplicate that doesn't mean this question will be deleted. The system is there so people get pointed in the right direction with different search queries

This is the solution:
Convert the numeric key value into a string key to avoid issues with numeric indices
{% set stringKey = 'value_' ~ value %}

This results in:

value_27value_32value_36value_36value_27value_32value_32

Check if the key exists and update its count, else set the count to 1
{% if attribute(valuesWithNewKey, stringKey) is defined %}
    {% set valuesWithNewKey = valuesWithNewKey|merge({ (stringKey): valuesWithNewKey[stringKey] + 1 }) %}
{% else %}
    {% set valuesWithNewKey = valuesWithNewKey|merge({ (stringKey): 1 }) %}
{% endif %}

Inside the for loop (value in valuesIntegers) when you print the stringKey and values you will get:
{% for value in valuesWithNewKey %}
    {{ value }}<br>
{% endfor %}


value_27 : 1value_32 : 1value_32 : 1value_36 : 1value_36 : 1value_36 : 1value_36 : 1value_36 : 1value_36 : 2value_27 : 2value_27 : 1value_27 : 2value_32 : 2value_32 : 2value_32 : 2value_32 : 2value_32 : 3value_32 : 2

Outside the for loop (value in valuesIntegers) after, replacing the 'value_' it will result in the desired output   
{% for stringKey, count in valuesWithNewKey %}
   {{ stringKey|replace({'value_':''}) ~ ' : ' ~ count }}<br>
{% endfor %}


27 : 232 : 336 : 2

The whole code:
 {% set valuesIntegers = [27, 32, 36, 36, 27, 32, 32] %}
 {% set valuesWithNewKey = {} %}

{% for value in valuesIntegers %}
   {% set stringKey = 'value_' ~ value %}

   {% if attribute(valuesWithNewKey, stringKey) is defined %}
     {% set valuesWithNewKey = valuesWithNewKey|merge({ (stringKey): valuesWithNewKey[stringKey] + 1 }) %}
   {% else %}
     {% set valuesWithNewKey = valuesWithNewKey|merge({ (stringKey): 1 }) %}
   {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for stringKey, count in valuesWithNewKey %}
   {{ stringKey|replace({'value_':''}) ~ ' : ' ~ count }}<br>
{% endfor %}


used inside the set counts structure.
{% set valuesIntegers = [27, 32, 36, 36, 27, 32, 32] %}

{% set counts = {} %}

{% for value in valuesIntegers %}
    {% if counts[value] is not defined %}
        {% set counts = counts|merge({ (value): 1 }) %}
    {% else %}
        {% set counts = counts|merge({ (value): counts[value] + 1 }) %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}

{% for key, count in counts %}
    {{ key }}: {{ count }}
{% endfor %}


Did you actually test this answer before posting or read the comments I've posted beneath the question? You can't use merge with numeric indices
